# Authenticate saml session from chrome extension

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension, saml, simplesamlphp

I've implemented [simpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) and setup a test environment by following the mentioned link, its working good so far. I'm able to authenticate users from provided IDPs. What I'm trying to do next is to get that SAML authenticated session in my chrome app and see if user is logged in or not.

Is it possible? any help is highly appreciated. Please let me know if my question is not clear enough.

Thanks!

Comment: Google Apps offers a SAML-based Single Sign-On (SSO) service, there are a number of existing open source and commercial identity provider solutions that can help you implement SSO with Google Apps. To see the reference: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation

Comment: Google Apps SAML is only for Google hosted apps, like gmail, google docs etc, right? I've my own App hosted on Web Store. I've a server with SAML setup on it. Im already using that server to authenticate user from my other website, now i want to authenticate my App user from my this server as well. Is it possible?